# HTML Tables - can I have an additional tbody before the thead?

Tags: html, html-table

I need add to some elements on top of a table in line with the columns of the said table.

This table contains a `<thead>` (which is required due to jquery.tablesorter plugin). I assumed that if I put another `<tbody>` on top of the `<thead>` I would be able to keep these elements in line with the rest of the columns, but both chrome and firefox render every `<tbody>` below the `<thead>`.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head</th><th>head</th><th>head</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td><td>4</td><td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Although I understand this, I still need to find a way to have these elements stay in line with specific columns.

Comment: Could you use utilize `<tfoot>`? Or you could use another table above the current one and make the columns fixed width? Or if they can't be fixed width use JS to resize them dynamically?

Comment: won't tfoot always be placed at the bottom?

Comment: The elements I need at the top, will be on top of the last 4 columns which are fixed width. So I could place div aligned to the right to make it look like it's part of it.

I'm trying to keep it in the table, as I would like to make use of the column index.

Comment: You can have multiple rows in `<thead>` - is that an option?

Comment: Oh dear, i'm so used to having a single row header that it didn't even cross my mind. I would be able to work with that yes.

You could post it as an answer. Thanks for making me feel like an idiot :( :P

Comment: I've posted an answer below, haha, no worries we're all terrible programmers really - stackoverflow makes us all a little bit better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multiple rows in `<thead>` like this:-

```
<table>

   <thead>

     <tr> <td>1</td> <td>1</td> </tr>

     <tr> <td>head</td> <td>head</td> </tr>

   </thead>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use an id (#) marker to identify that part that you want the js to work off and have the js use that id.

With that, have the `thead` first and the `tbody` last.

The variations you are describing may work - in the browser you using now, on the OS you are ok - and may be compliant a certain version of the HTML spec- but putting things in an unusual order is (in my expereince) just the kind of thing to not work, or work the same, everywhere and to eventually be the cause of much frustration, especially as the site grows in complexity.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use another table inside one tr, in your thead.  Althought, this is a totally ugly solution.

You can also place a div above your table using CSS.

Comment: I am allowed to have more than one tbody per table. Most of the columns in the table don't have fixed widths, but I think I might end up doing this. If there's no other way.

Comment: Multiple `<tbody>`s are allowed according to the HTML4 spec:- http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Correct table structure is:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

`<thead>` will always be on the top and `<tfoot>` will always be at the bottom.

---

Using `jQuery` you can swap `<thead>` and `<tbody>` content by:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTrigger').click(function() {
        var top = $('thead').html();
        var mid = $('tbody').html();
        $('thead').html(mid);
        $('tbody').html(top);
    });
});
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the question.  It is an answer to "how should a table be correctly formed in HTML" - a different question.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I mean, that if in the example there are three blocks of rows: `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, then they can be positioned by changing them to `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`. :) But, probably, that's not very good for markup reasons, because in `<thead>` will be stored actual "tbody" rows.

Comment: Yes, they can be repositioned, but what about the js issue (reason for the positioning to be off..) ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I've added sample `jQuery` code. It should swap rows between `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.